# YouTube API address is displaying invalid response when I tested using postman app for testing API

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api, fetch-api, http-status-code-401, rapidapi

I tested the YouTube api url I got from rapid api and the status code was 401 - invalid address. I need help ls

What else  can I do?

Answer (score 1):

`401` HTTP status code means you're not authorized to access the particular resource you were requesting.

Chances are you're either:

- not passing any credentials
- passing incorrect credentials
- using the wrong authentication scheme

Check [YouTube's API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube) for more details.